# Linq strangeness

Tags: linq, distinct

I was receiving repeating rows from this linq query:

```
             public static Func<DataContext, string, IQueryable<Building>>
            GearFilteredBuildings =
                CompiledQuery.Compile((DataContext db, string filter) =>
                    from b in db.Building 
                        join r in db.Router on b equals r.Building
                    orderby !b.Active
                    where filter.Length == 5 && r.Name.Substring(1, 5).ToLower() == filter
                        || filter.Substring(0, 3) == r.Name.Substring(3, 3).ToLower()
                    select b);
```

After some fiddling, I got the distinct Buildings with this:

```
        public static Func<DataContext, string, IQueryable<Building>>
            GearFilteredBuildings =
                CompiledQuery.Compile((DataContext db, string filter) =>
                    (from b in db.Building
                     join r in db.Router on b equals r.Building
                     orderby !b.Active
                     where filter.Length == 5 && r.Name.Substring(1, 5).ToLower() == filter
                         || filter.Substring(0, 3) == r.Name.Substring(3, 3).ToLower()
                     group b by b.Id into g
                         select g) as IQueryable<Building>);
```

Is this an acceptable solution?  How else might this be done?

Comment: If you join, you will see duplication of parent rows in the event of multiple child rows. This is just how join works.  It's not "strange" at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure (couldn't test it IDE) but `select...join...lalala` can replaced with Linq-Chain syntax:

```
db.Routers
   .Where(r => filter.Length == 5 && r.Name.Substring(1, 5).ToLower() == filter || filter.Substring(0, 3) == r.Name.Substring(3, 3).ToLower())
   .GroupBy(r => r.Building)
   .Select(g => g.Key)
   .OrderBy(b => !b.Active)
```

Also: as I can see no `join`s are really requred in your query, as you have navigation properties (`r.Building`)in your model.

Or another approach could be used, select all needed buildings, and use `.Distinct()` afterwards:

```
db.Routers
    .Where (r => filter.Length == 5 && r.Name.Substring(1, 5).ToLower() == filter || filter.Substring(0, 3) == r.Name.Substring(3, 3).ToLower())
    .Select(r => r.Building)
    .Distinct()
    .OrderBy(b => !b.Active)
```

Comment: The first suggestion worked.  The second suggestion did not work because the Distinct() method had no affect on the result set.  I had tried (the linq statement).Distinct() to no avail as well.  I also overwrote Building's GetHashCodeMethod() with no effect.  Thanks so much for the answer.

Comment: and here it is as linq:                          from r in db.Router
                        where filter.Length == 5 && r.Name.Substring(1, 5).ToLower() == filter
                            || filter.Substring(0, 3) == r.Name.Substring(3, 3).ToLower()
                        group r by r.Building into grp
                        select grp.Key